# Низкоуровневый захват экрана, скриншот. c#

Tags: c#, rdp, скриншот

пишу RDP программу вопрос такой, есть ли возможность в языке c# на низком уровне считывать данные отрисовки изображения на мониторе с видеокарты или памяти перед отправкой в виде сигнала и конвертировать это все в byte массив.

Такой способ:

```
Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width , Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height );
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
printscreen.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Достаточно медленный, делает двойную работу и очень сильно ест ресурсы процессора, ни как не подходит для потоковой передачи изображения с рабочего стола без сильной задержки.

Comment: А что будете делать, если на сервере не будет монитора? Будет ваша программа поддерживать такой сценарий?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500950/12888024

Comment: Если нет монитора, то отрисовка на низком уровне все равно происходит.